# How to install pkg-config correctly?

Tags: unix, gcc, cygwin

When I tried installing pkg-config, I got this error:

> configure: error: Either a previously installed pkg-config or
> "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" could not be found. Please set GLIB_CFLAGS and
> GLIB_LIBS to the correct values or pass --with-internal-glib to
> configure to use the bundled copy.

And then when I included `--with-internal-glib` next to `./configure`, I get this error:

> configure: error: *** No iconv() implementation found in C library or
> libiconv configure: error: ./configure failed for glib

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cygcheck -p` to find the package to add to your Cygwin installation that your code is looking for:

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/lib/libiconv
Found 7 matches for usr/lib/libiconv
...
libiconv-devel-1.16-2 - libiconv-devel: Unicode iconv() implementation
libiconv-1.14-2 - libiconv: Unicode iconv() implementation (installed binaries and support files)
```

You need to install the `libiconv-devel` package
that will provide the headers and the import libraries. After installation you will have:

```
 $ cygcheck -l libiconv-devel |grep "a$"
/usr/lib/libcharset.a
/usr/lib/libcharset.dll.a
/usr/lib/libiconv.a
/usr/lib/libiconv.dll.a
```

you can also see if the available glib (libglib2.0-devel) is suitable for your build

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/lib/libglib
Found 10 matches for usr/lib/libglib
glib2.0-debuginfo-2.50.3-1 - glib2.0-debuginfo: Debug info for glib2.0
...
libglib2.0-devel-2.54.3-1 - libglib2.0-devel: GNOME core C function library (development)
...
libglibmm2.4-devel-2.54.1-2 - libglibmm2.4-devel: C++ bindings for glib-2.4 (development)
```

Do not forget to install also `cygwin-devel`